# distinction of function templates

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe4

I am now studying the function template.

I tried following code.

```
template <typename TYPE>
TYPE& Max(TYPE& a, TYPE& b)
{
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}

template < >
char* Max<char*>(char* a, char* b)
{
    return (strcmp(a, b) > 0) ? a : b;
}

template < >
const char* Max<const char*>(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    return (strcmp(a, b) > 0) ? a : b;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    float a = 3.14;
    float b = 2.718;
    float c = Max(a, b);

    char *ca = "abc";
    char *cb = "def";
    char *cmp = Max(ca, cb);    // error (E2015)
}
```

On C++ Builder XE4,  I received following error.

```
E2015 Ambiguity between 'char *Ma<>(char *, char *) at Unit1.cpp:43' 
and 'Max<>(char *,char *)at Unit1.cpp:43'
```

In this case, what should I do to avoid the Error 2015?

Comment: First, cut and paste the error message so we can see what it really said (right now, it's clearly wrong, such as calling one of the two `Ma` instead of `Max`).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I pasted the error message by way of my text editor, in which I may delete part of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is rather nonstandard, and it indicates that your compiler is badly outdated.

First, those specializations aren't allowed. The primary template mentions references (`TYPE &`), so the explicit specializations also have to use the same types. They are allowed to change the function body of the original template, not the signature.

After that is fixed, it passes the IDEone online compiler with no more errors.

```
#include <string.h>

template <typename TYPE>
TYPE& Max(TYPE& a, TYPE& b)
{
    return (a > b ? a : b);
}

template < >
char*& Max<char*&>(char*& a, char*& b)
{
    return (strcmp(a, b) > 0) ? a : b;
}

template < >
const char*& Max<const char*>(const char*& a, const char*& b)
{
    return (strcmp(a, b) > 0) ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    float a = 3.14;
    float b = 2.718;
    float c = Max(a, b);

    char *ca = "abc";
    char *cb = "def";
    char *cmp = Max(ca, cb);    // no error
}
```

http://ideone.com/gR9VFX

It might be a good idea to ask your instructor to upgrade, and point at discrepancies between your classroom compiler and IDEone (or another online compiler; they're always available and always free, just like their underlying software) for encouragement.

Besides compiler and correctness issues,

1. The non-const `char *&` business is redundant. Since the function never modifies anything you can just implement it for `const char` and allow that to be used when the pointer isn't `const`. Perhaps both are needed because of how specialization works, but:
2. Function specialization is almost always a bad idea. For example, you want `const char *` parameters here, not `const char *&`. Just remove the `template <>` line and the template arguments on the next line, and you will get an overload instead. This program is an exercise in extraneous templating, which just makes things hard for no reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Potatoswatter. So, I have to use the same types as `TYPE &`. Then, the sample code you gave me worked without error on my IDE. Thank you also for your further recommendations on the template usages. I will keep these in mind for my future work.

Comment: I found the ideone web site very useful. Thank you also for letting me know this web site.